# vue js select boxes in v-for

Tags: drop-down-menu, vue.js

Another Vue JS question please

i have the following

```
<div v-for="benefit in benefits" track-by="$index" class="Quote__list">
 <div class="Benefit Form--default">
  <select v-model="benefitType" @change="updateBenefitItem($index)">
    <option value="Teacher" selected>Teacher</option>
    <option value="Care Taker">Care Taker</option>
    <option value="Support Staff">Support Staff</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

i have 3 items in benefits so i get 3 select boxes. On my change method it even logs the correct item thats selected

```
updateBenefitItem(n)
{
  console.log(this.benefitType)
},
```

My problem is that the values in all the select boxes on my page updates to the same value, i need to know how to treat select boxes in a loop as individuals.

is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks Sam

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: hiya, yeah - https://jsfiddle.net/e5rgy7tx/5/ any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/5y19e9oc/4/

```
v-model="benefitType[$index]"
```

Use an index on the array you use as v-model

Comment: had to do a few tweaks to my code but this should work perfect! thank you so much